# Functional equations involving definite integrals

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals, book-recommendation

Are there any books or online sources available which involves functional equations involving integrals?

Here is an example,

> Find the number of continuous functions $f:[0,1] \rightarrow (-\infty,\infty) $satisfying the condition
>
> $$\int_0^{1}(f(x))^2dx=2\int_0^{1}f(x)dx$$

Comment: Any kind of help will be appreciated!